# errors when i use bgslibrary example code

Tags: c++, opencv

im working with windows 10, opencv 3.0, and visual studio 2012. im trying to use bgslibrary example code. When I try to build the bgslibrary I get the following error C2864

```
#include <iostream>'
#include <cv.h>'
#include <highgui.h>
#include "package_bgs\bgslibrary.h"
#include "package_bgs\FrameDifference.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  CvCapture *capture = 0;
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

  if(!capture){
    std::cerr << "Cannot initialize video!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  IBGS *bgs;
  bgs = new FrameDifference;

  IplImage *frame;
  while(1)
  {
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!frame) break;

    cv::Mat img_input = cv::cvarrToMat(frame);
    cv::imshow("Input", img_input);

    cv::Mat img_mask;
    cv::Mat img_bkgmodel;

    // by default, it shows automatically the foreground mask image
    bgs->process(img_input, img_mask, img_bkgmodel);

    //if(!img_mask.empty())
    //  cv::imshow("Foreground", img_mask);
    //  do something

    if(cvWaitKey(33) >= 0)
    break;
  }

  delete bgs;

  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

  return 0;
}
```

1    error C2864: 'bgslibrary::algorithms::IBGS::firstTime' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
   2    error C2864: 'bgslibrary::algorithms::IBGS::showOutput' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class 
   5    error C2864: 'bgslibrary::algorithms::IBGS::firstTime' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

```
16  IntelliSense: data member initializer is not allowed    c:\Users\izzaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project1_bgslibrary\Project1_bgslibrary\package_bgs\CodeBook.h 48
17  IntelliSense: data member initializer is not allowed    c:\Users\izzaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project1_bgslibrary\Project1_bgslibrary\package_bgs\CodeBook.h 49
```

Comment: Please, have a look at [A background subtraction library on github](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary). _Supported Compilers are:_ ... _MSVC 2015, 2017_. VS2012 is just too old.

Comment: I get this error when i use MSVC 2015.                                                                            Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl libtwopointsModel_AllocInit_8u_C1R(struct twopointsModel *,unsigned char const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?libtwopointsModel_AllocInit_8u_C1R@@YAHPEAUtwopointsModel@@PEBEII@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl bgslibrary::algorithms::TwoPoints::process(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat &,class cv::Mat &)" (?process@TwoPoints@algorithms@bgslibrary@@UEAAXAEBVMat@cv@@AEAV45@1@Z)

Comment: May be, the [issue page of the github project](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary/issues) would be a better place to post if something is broken.